# How to Redirect stderr in a powershell for loop using .net methods

Tags: .net, powershell, error-handling

I am working on a script that will get a list of all domain joined computers so my script can remote in to them and execute commands across the domain, however the system I am running doesn't have access to the active directory module. My solution was to use a .net method to query for the information but I am having trouble getting errors to redirect to null in my script. What I am getting is when the code executes, if a system is not up I will get the error "the network path was not found". I need to send these errors to null but no matter where I place my redirection I still get the error. The problem is that these errors will cause the rest of script to stop working.
This is my code for finding domain computers:

```
$Domainmachines = (([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)").Children) | Where {$_.schemaclassname -eq 'computer'} 
Foreach( $machine in $Domainmachines) {
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -InputObject $machine 

} 2>$null
```

I have tried placing the "2>$null"  after the select-object command, in the variable and as shown outside the for loop. I have also tried saving everything to a variable, with a "2>$null" at the end of the variable, inside the for loop and then writing the contents to the screen but it still prints all of the errors to the screen and causes the script to hang.

Comment: If the issue is machines that cannot be contacted, in my opinion a better solution is to use Test-Connection to not try machines that are not on.

Comment: Is there a reason `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` couldn't be used? `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -InputObject $machine -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: As for this ---"however the system I am running doesn't have access to the active directory module." it does not need them on the system to use them. You can use PoSH Implicit remoting to any DC in your environment to use them, no install required. "Remoting the Implicit Way
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/09/08/remoting-the-implicit-way https://4sysops.com/archives/using-implicit-powershell-remoting-to-import-remote-modules." However, nothing wrong with going the .Net route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection operators only work when stuck at the end of a pipeline - the `foreach($thing in $collection){}` loop statement is not a valid pipeline element.

To get around this, you could wrap the entire thing in a script block and dot-source it:

```
. {
    $Domainmachines = (([adsi]"WinNT://$((Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain)").Children) | Where {$_.schemaclassname -eq 'computer'} 
    Foreach( $machine in $Domainmachines) {
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -InputObject $machine 

    } 
} 2>$null
```

Comment: Nicely done; if there's no subsequent pipeline element (in which case one-by-one enumeration may be preferable), you can also use the subexpression operator `$(foreach (...) { ... }) 2>$null` (or the array-subexpression operator,  `@(...)`).

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, any valid expression nesting mechanism should work! I just find `.{} 2>&1` more... eh, natural, I don't know why :-)

Comment: `. { }` does have the distinct advantage of being pipeline-friendly (passing the script block's output object by object through the pipeline).