# Error redirection is not working in powershell

Tags: powershell, redirect

when I type '4abd' in powershell it gives the following output.

4abd : The term '4abd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ 4abd
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (4abd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I want to redirect this error to a file. I tried all the following ways:

```
4abd 2>&1>>"D:\\xyz.txt"
4abd 2>&1 >> D:\\xyz.txt
4abd 2>&1 >> xyz.txt
4abd 2>&1 >> "xyz.txt"
4abd 2>"D:\\xyz.txt"
4abd 2>D:\\xyz.txt
```

But nothing is working out. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Invoke-Expression` to accomplish this. The reason that `2>&1` isn't working for you is because the command is not generating the error, PowerShell is. So instead give PowerShell a cmdlet that it knows how to use, and if that cmdlet generates an error it can redirect it.

```
. { Invoke-Expression "4abd" } 2>&1 | Set-Content xyz.txt
```

Comment: the file xyz.txt is created but it's not saving error in the file

Comment: [Wrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526109/how-to-redirect-stderr-in-a-powershell-for-loop-using-net-methods/48526263#48526263)

Comment: Right, it needed to be wrapped. Updated answer, tested, and it now works as expected.